# How to detect specific string over serial using C

Tags: serial, c

I am connecting my Raspberry Pi to a device using the serial port to record data coming from the device at 19.2 kbit/s. Currently I am using a USB-to-serial adapter, but this could change in the future.

The data transmitted from the device is something like:

```
R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234<LF>
R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234<LF>
R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234<LF>
R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234<LF>
A-990I0123C-990T0123S0123D0123<LF>
R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234<LF>
R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234<LF>
R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234R1234<LF>
```

The only bit that I need to record is the line starting with A. I want to write a program to detect this line, and record it, prefarably in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) (as this is the language that I have had the most experience in, although I am far from an expert).

I can't think of a good strategy to quickly read, recognise, and save the required data, and I was wondering if there was a function, or similar, to detect a particular sequence in an ongoing stream of data?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have opened the serial device as a FILE *.

Use fgets to fetch each line.
Store the line if the first character is 'A' otherwise discard the line.
Repeat.